# Unresponsive Macbook Pro. Black Screen. Can't Reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

The other day my MacBook Pro just spontaneously halted during regular usage.
 The screen went black, aside from the mouse cursor appearing once every 10 seconds (exactly).

I don't seem to be able to move the cursor myself and upon trying to reboot the device (cold), I get the Apple Inc. logo / loading progress-bar combo, and then its straight back to being an unresponsive black screen with a cursor that flashes at ten second intervals.

Does anybody understand what's going on and/or how to fix the problem so that I can resume normal operation? Cheers.

---

Hardware:

- MacBook Pro.
- 15" Retina Display.
- Early 2013.
- i7 Processor.
- OS X Yosemite.
- 8GB RAM.
- 500GB Solid-State Storage.

  ---

Update:

SMC reset worked, but no change. NVRAM reset worked, i think (had to type firmware password) but it brought me to the recovery tools. Cannot boot into Safe-Mode or Single-User-Mode. Apple Diagnostics / Apple Hardware Test fails to launch. Recovery-Mode start-up brings me to the same screen as the NVRAM reset. Verbose-Mode also fails.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the NVRAM, SMC?  Can you boot into safe mode?

Comment: @Allan Nope. None of those help. SMC reset worked, but no change. NVRAM reset worked, i think (had to type firmware password) but it brought me to the recovery tools. Cannot boot into Safe-Mode or Single-User-Mode. Apple Diagnostics / Apple Hardware Test fails to launch. Recovery-Mode start-up brings me to the same screen as the NVRAM reset. Verbose-Mode also fails.

Comment: Interesting that the diagnostics fails to launch.  Do you have any bootable media?  Can you boot from a USB or DVD installer?

Comment: I would say so, I haven't tried. Is that relevant? I will check. I'll try and boot a live Debian distro off a thumb-drive.

Comment: It removes your internal SSD from the equation.  If you can't boot off the USB or DVD, you have (most likely) logic board issues.